# 7zip - does it have a case sensitive option?

Tags: linux, 7-zip

I would like to archive some folders on my linux machine using the Windows 7zip application but it fails with duplicate filename error due to not being case sensitive e.g. mydiff and myDiff.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `-ssc` switch. The [manual](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/ssc.htm) says it will "set case-sensitive mode".

Comment: Thanks. That works if I use the cmd line. Do you know how to change the windows default for the gui ? I like the simplicity of having to just right click on a folder and add it to an existing archive.